# St.Thomas Aquinas on Papacy

Tags: catholicism, papacy, thomas-aquinas, authority

What are the writings of St.Thomas Aquinas on papacy and church authority?

Comment: List of Works by Thomas Aquinas : [Wiki-List of Works-Thomas Aquinas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_by_Thomas_Aquinas). These are, firstly, in Subject order, then, secondly, in Chronological order.

Comment: This question probably needs to be more narrowly targeted. Do you have a specific question regarding Aquinas' theology of the papacy.

Comment: @jaredad7 No, but I am currently studying St.Thomas Aquinas's view on various subjects.

Comment: @NigelJ thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

St. Thomas did not write a treatise [*ex professo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ex_professo) on the papacy or ecclesiology, like St. Robert Bellarmine did ([*On the Roman Pontiff*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=title:%22On%20the%20Roman%20Pontiff%22), [*On the Church Militant*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8256)), but St. Thomas did address the question in other contexts.

See St. Thomas's questions on Christ as Head of the Church ([*Summa Theologica* III q. 8](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP008.html)), esp. [a. 6 "Whether it is proper to Christ to be Head of the Church?"](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP008.html#TPQ8A6THEP1), where he distinguishes visible and invisible headship:

> ## Invisible vs. visible headship
>
> In [*ibid.* a. 6](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP008.html#TPQ8A6THEP1) ("Whether it is proper to Christ to be Head of
> the Church?") co., St. Thomas explains that a
>
> > head influences the other members in two ways.
> >
> > 1. by a certain **intrinsic influence**, inasmuch as motive and sensitive force flow from the head to the other members;
> > 2. by a certain **exterior guidance**, inasmuch as by sight and the senses, which are rooted in the head, man is guided in his exterior
> >    acts.
>
> Christ the Head influences by #1, whereas the "great men, heads of the
> people" ([Amos 6:1](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=35&ch=6&l=1-#x)), such as bishops, influence by #2.
>
> Christ's headship differs from human headship because
>
> > 1. **Christ is** the **Head** of all who pertain to the Church **in every place and time and state**; but all other men are called heads
> >    with reference to certain special places, as bishops of their
> >    Churches. Or with reference to a determined time as the Pope is the
> >    head of the whole Church, viz. during the time of his Pontificate, and
> >    with reference to a determined state, inasmuch as they are in the
> >    state of wayfarers.
> > 2. **Christ is** the **Head** of the Church **by His own power and authority**; while others are called heads, as taking Christ's place,
> >    according to [2 Cor. 2:10](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=54&ch=2&l=10-#x), "For what I have pardoned, if I have
> >    pardoned anything, for your sakes I have done it in the person of
> >    Christ," and [2 Cor. 5:20](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=54&ch=5&l=20-#x), "For Christ therefore we are
> >    ambassadors, God, as it were, exhorting by us."
>
> #2 explains why a Pope is called the Vicar of Christ. "Vicar" is
> related to the word "[vicarious](https://oed.com/view/Entry/223102)," that which "takes or supplies
> the place of another thing or person"; a Pope represents Christ.

<sup>source: [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/78228/1787) to the question "[Is the pope the head of the Church for Catholics?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/78226/1787)"</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your response